# SSH: guarding stdout against disconnect

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

My server deployment script triggers a long-running process through SSH, like so:

```
ssh host 'install.sh'
```

Since my internet connection at home is not the best, I can sometimes be disconnected while the `install.sh` is running. (This is easily simulated by closing the terminal window.) I would really like for the `install.sh` script to keep running in those cases, so that I don't end up with interrupted `apt-get` processes and similar nuisances.

The reason why `install.sh` gets killed seems to be that stdout and stderr are closed when the SSH session is yanked, so writing to them fails. (It's not an issue of [SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP), by the way -- using [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) makes no difference.) If I put `touch ~/1 && echo this fails && touch ~/2` into `install.sh`, only `~/1` is created.

So running `ssh host 'install.sh &> install.out'` solves the problem, but then I lose any "live" progress and error output.

So my question is: What's an easy/idiomatic way to run a process through SSH so that it doesn't crash if SSH dies, but so that I can still see the output as it runs?

---

Solutions I have tried:

- When I run things manually, I use `screen` for cases like this, but I don't think it will be of much help here because I need to run `install.sh` automatically from a shell script. Screen seems to be made for interactive use (it complains "Must be connected to a terminal.").
- Using `install.sh 2>&1 | tee install.out` didn't help either (silly of me to think it might).
- You can redirect stdout/stderr into `install.out` and then `tail -f` it. The following snippet actually works:

  ```
  touch install.out &&  # so tail does not bark (race condition)
  (install.sh < /dev/null &> install.out &
  tail --pid "$!" -F install.out)
  ```

  But surely there must a less awkward way to do the same thing?

Comment: (Since two people voted this off-topic... I wasn't sure whether Server Fault would be the better place, but as this is about shell scripting, I figured it'd be better-fitting here?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using screen:

```
screen ./install.sh
```

If your ssh session gets interrupted, you can simply reattach to the session via another ssh connection:

```
screen -x
```

You can provide a terminal to your ssh session using the -t switch:

```
ssh -t server screen ./install.sh
```

Comment: As I said in my question, this doesn't work non-interactively: `Must be connected to a terminal.`

Comment: Ah, nice -- +1 for your answer. Actually, with `-tt` (to force terminal creation), I do get a screen terminal with output. I still get an entire page of blank lines after my output though -- it just doesn't feel very usable. I'm not sure if it's possible to make it behave better -- after all, this is kind of misusing screen for something it wasn't made for. But it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

install.sh 2>&1 | tee install.out

if the only issue is not getting stderr. You didn't say exactly why the tee wasn't acceptable. You may need the other nohup/stdin tweaks.

Comment: I'm afraid adding `2>&1` to the tee pipe doesn't help (I just edited my question to reflect this) -- it simply doesn't make a difference, the script still gets killed.  Guarding either process with nohup doesn't make a difference either: `nohup install.sh < /dev/null 2>&1 | nohup tee install.out`

Comment: @Ben: Right, that seems to be the case. The `tee` simply dies along with the SSH session, and then `install.sh` dies because its pipe went away.